# Lumen - Namespace issue

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, lumen

I am in trouble with namespaces in lumen/laravel. My project structure is following:

- App/Http/Controllers

  - ExampleController

If I would call my Controller by a route:

```
Route::get('/', 'ExampleController@test');
```

I've got the exception, that this class `App\Http\Controllers\ExampleController` is not found! In my ExampleController I've signed it with namespace `App\Http\Controllers;`

Is there any explaination, because I dont changed the default namespace and I need to group it with `namespace => App\Http\Controllers`. If I use that namespace grouping, it would work?!

Comment: what do you mean by "namespace grouping" and that you have to "group it"?

Comment: $app->group(['namespace' => '...']); That I meant with "grouping"

Comment: Can you post your `ExampleController`. Also, have you tried a `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: You can find it there: http://pastebin.com/Shc5JE5s and yes if tried composer update, composer dump-autoload